# Can't deserialize System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection in a complex object

Tags: c#, json, collections, deserialization

I have this complex object which include multiple property of "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection", but this collection won't deserialized, it always return with nothing in the element. for example:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public string ProductCategoryName;
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Product> Product
}

{
  "ProductCategoryName": "Appliance",
  "Product": [
    {
       "entry1": "entry1",
       "entry2": "entry2"
    },
    {
       "entry1": "entry1",
       "entry2": "entry2"
    }
  ]
}


var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };

var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProductCategory>(productCategoryString, options);
```

In the result, Product has 0 items, ProductCategoryName deserialized properly. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to use the type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` ? Or would a more typical array / list work for you. I have a suspicion that the target type might be the issue here

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, and then I changed to List. It didn't work either. Since I created the class by converting third party schema, there is an initialization for those collections. But when I remove those initialization, the object value will be null instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle and it worked. I suspect that "Product" lacks public setters or setters at all. have a look at this fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/GcGoUK

Comment: In the same vein, by default, Newtonsoft.Json requires a parameterless constructor to be able to construc the deserialized objects

Comment: this class is third party generated, I didn't notice some of the property is "private set"!